# Rule to set a variable in Makefile not working as expected

Tags: c, makefile

I'm writing a makefile that can compile different projects depending on the rule used. For this I need to set certain variables to set paths and generate the right output files.

This is the section that is currently not working:

```
bubblesort: OUTPROG = bubblesort
bubblesort: APP_PATH    = $(SRCS)/bubblesort
bubblesort: OBJS    = ../programs/bubblesort/bubblesort.o
bubblesort: $(COMMON_OBJS) $(OBJS)
    @ echo "<-------------------- Making Bubblesort -------------------->"
    @ echo "<-------------------- Linking files -------------------->"
    $(LD) $(COMMON_OBJS) $(OBJS) $(LDFLAGS)
    @ echo "<-------------------- ELF to Binary File -------------------->"
    $(OC) $(OCFLAGS) $(TARGET) $(BINOUT)
    @ echo "<-------------------- Binary to Verilog Conversion -------------------->"
    $(R2V) $(R2VPARAMS) 


# This is the rule to transform any c code to object file via compilation.
%.o : %.c
    @ echo "<-------------------- Compiling C Source Files -------------------->"
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS_APP) $< -o $@
```

What happens is that the compilation of the c sources to generate the .o is never invoked (the %.o: %.c rule). However this works:

```
OBJS        = ../programs/bubblesort/bubblesort.o
bubblesort: OUTPROG = bubblesort
bubblesort: APP_PATH    = $(SRCS)/bubblesort
bubblesort: $(COMMON_OBJS) $(OBJS)
    @ echo "<-------------------- Making Bubblesort -------------------->"
    @ echo "<-------------------- Linking files -------------------->"
    $(LD) $(COMMON_OBJS) $(OBJS) $(LDFLAGS)
    @ echo "<-------------------- ELF to Binary File -------------------->"
    $(OC) $(OCFLAGS) $(TARGET) $(BINOUT)
    @ echo "<-------------------- Binary to Verilog Conversion -------------------->"
    $(R2V) $(R2VPARAMS)
```

My question is simply why? I would appreciate any input.

EDIT:

Also how can I make the prerequisite depend on the rule invoked?

EDIT 2:

Following the advice from Etan Raiser I modified my code to look like this:

```
bubblesort: OUTPROG = bubblesort
bubblesort: APP_PATH    = $(SRCS)/bubblesort
bubblesort: $(COMMON_OBJS) ../programs/bubblesort/bubblesort.o creation

creation: $^
    @ echo "<-------------------- Making in general -------------------->"
    @ echo "<-------------------- Linking files -------------------->"
    $(LD) $^ $(LDFLAGS)
    @ echo "<-------------------- ELF to Binary File -------------------->"
    $(OC) $(OCFLAGS) $(TARGET) $(BINOUT)
    @ echo "<-------------------- Binary to Verilog Conversion -------------------->"
    $(R2V) $(R2VPARAMS) 
    @ echo "<-------------------- Creating Obj Dump -------------------->"
    $(OD) $(ODFLAGS) $(TARGET) > $(APP_PATH)/$(OUTPROG)_DUMP.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a question of variable expansion time. (See [How `make` Reads a Makefile](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Reading-Makefiles).)

The target line `bubblesort: $(COMMON_OBJS) $(OBJS)` is expanded immediately.

The target-specific variable line `bubblesort: OBJS    = ../programs/bubblesort/bubblesort.o` isn't "executed" (actually doing the assignment) until the `bubblesort` target is being run.

Instead of this (which doesn't work):

```
bubblesort: OUTPROG = bubblesort
bubblesort: APP_PATH    = $(SRCS)/bubblesort
bubblesort: OBJS    = ../programs/bubblesort/bubblesort.o
bubblesort: $(COMMON_OBJS) $(OBJS)
    @ echo "<-------------------- Making Bubblesort -------------------->"
    @ echo "<-------------------- Linking files -------------------->"
    $(LD) $(COMMON_OBJS) $(OBJS) $(LDFLAGS)
    @ echo "<-------------------- ELF to Binary File -------------------->"
    $(OC) $(OCFLAGS) $(TARGET) $(BINOUT)
    @ echo "<-------------------- Binary to Verilog Conversion -------------------->"
    $(R2V) $(R2VPARAMS)
```

and which needs the `$(OBJ)` variable for the `$(LD)` call.

You can use:

```
bubblesort: OUTPROG = bubblesort
bubblesort: APP_PATH    = $(SRCS)/bubblesort
bubblesort: $(COMMON_OBJS) ../programs/bubblesort/bubblesort.o
    @ echo "<-------------------- Making Bubblesort -------------------->"
    @ echo "<-------------------- Linking files -------------------->"
    $(LD) $^ $(LDFLAGS)
    @ echo "<-------------------- ELF to Binary File -------------------->"
    $(OC) $(OCFLAGS) $(TARGET) $(BINOUT)
    @ echo "<-------------------- Binary to Verilog Conversion -------------------->"
    $(R2V) $(R2VPARAMS)
```

Which works and uses the built-in `$^` automatic variable for its intended purpose.

Comment: Thank you I've edited the question to include asking how can I can modify my makefile so that the prerequisite depends on the rule invoked.

Comment: It does depend on it. If you listed any `.o` files there manually then the value of `$(OBJS)` in the rule for that file would be the `bubblesort`-specific value. You just can't use that in a prerequisite the way you wanted to.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand. So I'll try to express myself better. The way things are right now if I want two different rules (say one for bubblesort and one for quicksort) I need to write the recipe for it in the exact same way chagin OBJS for something like OBJS_QUICKSORT which contains the list of .o files for quicksort. But everything else is the same and I'm trying to work around copy and pasting so much code. Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: Don't use target-specific variables use individual variables. So `COMMON_OBJS`, `QUICKSORT_OBJS`, and `BUBBLESORT_OBJS`. Or don't' use those at all and just write them on the prerequisite lines directly (since you can, and should, use `$^` and the other [automatic variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables) in your recipe lines).

Comment: Thanks, but I still don't understand the alternative. I've read the page you showed me, however I did not understand how using the $^ would help me.  Maybe an example?

Comment: The reason you are trying to use the target-specific variables is because you are then  using `$(BUBBLESORT_OBJS)` in the recipe lines. Don't do that and you don't need the variable and can just write `bubblesort: $(COMMON_OBJS) ../programs/bubblesort/bubblesort.o` as the target line and then use `$^` in the recipe.

Comment: Thank you. But it still doesn't work. Obviously I'm implementing it wrong, but since I can't find an example that does what I want it is very hard to Debug. I've provided the code that I wrote in my edited question.

Answer (score 0):

When writing the macros, like OBJS, use ':=' 
    so the macro creation will be performed only once
    rather than repeated at each invocation of the macro.

The first word, before a ':' is a target name.
    Everything to the right of the ':' is dependencies for that target
    I'm a bit surprised that the make did not fail 
    due to multiple duplicate targets.

A better way to write those rules would be:

```
# when invoking 'make', use 'target=bubblesort'
# so the same makefile can be used for several targets:

APP_PATH    := $(SRC_PATH)/$(target)/
SRCS        := $(wildcard $(APP_PATH)*.c)
OBJS        := ../programs/$(target)/$(basename:$(SRCS):.c=.o)
$(target)   : $(COMMON_OBJS) $(OBJS)
    # 
    # ========= LINKING ${target} ==============
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) $(COMMON_OBJS) $(OBJS) -o $(target) 
    #<-------------------- ELF to Binary File -------------------->"
    $(OC) $(OCFLAGS) $(TARGET) $(BINOUT)
    #<-------------------- Binary to Verilog Conversion ---------->"
    $(R2V) $(R2VPARAMS) 
    # ========= finished ${target} =============


# This is the rule to transform any c code to object file via compilation.
%.o : %.c
    # ========= COMPILING $< TO $@ =========
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS_APP) -c $< -o $@  
    # ========= END $< TO $@ =========
```

However, the posted rules fail to take into account:

1. the source code #include dependencies
2. the dependency lists need to be generated for each .c file
3. the appropriate dependency list needs to be expanded
      on the '%o.%c'  line
4. the dependency list(s) need to be referenced via path
      on the '${CC}' line in the form of '-Ipath' parameters
5. if the dependency lists are not generated/used, then
      a change in a header file will fail to force
      a re-compile/re-link, etc

Comment: Some of the points here are quite useful but the formatting makes it very difficult to make sense of this answer. Also in this specific case `:=` doesn't gain anything really. This also doesn't allow building both at once. And `-Dtarget=bubblesort` isn't correct it would be `make target=bubblesort`.

Comment: @EtanReisner, please indicate what is difficult about reading the posting, so I can improve on such posting in the future

Comment: BTW: the lines within a rule, that begin with '#' will be properly expanded and echo'd to the user as the makefile runs

Comment: @EtanReisner, using := rather than : in the macros makes a big difference even in this little project. It would be a bad idea to try building multiple projects at the same invocation of this make file as it would clutter the make file. However, there could easily be a higher level make file that just contains a recursive make invocation for each desired project.

Comment: What big difference does it make in this makefile? There aren't any shell commands or `$(wildcard)` calls (which are costly to run more than once) and most variables are only used once on top of that. It doesn't need to clutter the makefile really at all just duplicate the lines per-target and have individual targets (but that's besides the point).